# grep for timestamp and word

Tags: bash, grep

So I am trying to grep through a log file counting lines that contain a time stamp that is within the last 30 minutes and a word.
I have working code for finding the time stamp:

```
grep "^$(date -d -30minute +'%Y-%m-%d %H')" /path/to/the/derp | wc -l
```

An example log file could be:

```
2014-08-07 00:00:03.001 000 GoogleGeoCodeService blah blah blah
2014-08-07 00:00:01.001 000 carrier check java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

If both entries ocured within last half hour, how do I count the second line but not the first? I have tried just adding another pipe but I never get the correct result:

```
grep "^$(date -d -30minute +'%Y-%m-%d %H')" /path/to/the/derp | wc -l | grep -i "exception"
```

Comment: The `date` trick only works if current minutes are > 30.

Comment: @choroba Huh I hadn't noticed that in practice but thank you. Do you have suggestions on other method of doing this?

Comment: I'd probably use Perl.

Comment: To get the second line, remove `| wc -l` before calling `grep` a second time and try again. You are reducing the output to a number with `wc -l`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ok makes sense. I should do both greps and then reduce to a number? I want the count of lines that meet the timestamp and contain 'exception' not the lines themselves. I am just trying to get a number of matches.

Comment: Oh, yes, by all means, do your `grep`s then reduce to a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you're `grep`ing for date stamps that are exactly 30 minutes ago instead of any time in the last 30 minutes.

You could accomplish what you want with Awk by passing the current shell's date in seconds as a variable. Then you can convert the datestamp in the log to date in seconds and subtract that from the current date variable to see if it's in the last 30 minutes (1800 seconds).

```
awk -v current=$(date +%s) -v IGNORECASE=1 -F\. 'BEGIN {
    n=0
}
/^[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}./ && /exception/ {
    time=$1
    format="\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 \\6"
    seconds=mktime(gensub(/(....)-(..)-(..) (..):(..):(..)/, format, "", time))
    if((current - seconds) <= 1800)
        n++
}END{
    print n
}' /path/to/the/derp
```

Answer (score 1):

Going on what you have there, just move the `wc` to the end:

```
grep "^$(date -d -30minute +'%Y-%m-%d %H')" /path/to/the/derp |
  grep -i "exception" |
  wc -l
```

But in fact this can be simplified:

```
grep -ic "^$(date -d -30minute +'%Y-%m-%d %H').*exception" /path/to/the/derp
```

Although the awk solution seems like a good way around your date issue.